# How does AUFS store deleted files?

Tags: aufs

When I change a file in an [AUFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs)-mount, that change gets stored somehow in the rw-layer.

It is clear how new/changed files are stored in the rw-layer, but how get deleted files remembered there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All union filesystems with read-only and read-write branches use some form of "whiteout" marker on a read-write branch to suppress a file that exists on a read-only branch. AUFS is no different.

For AUFS, the whiteout markers are files called:

```
.wh.<filename>
```

located in the same directory where the deleted file used to live, and where `<filename>` is the filename of the file that was deleted.

Ref: [aufs manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/aufs.5.html), [information about whiteout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39826/what-does-whiteout-mean-in-a-copy-on-write-filesystem)